# How to snap two objects together in Unity while runtime - no gridsystem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

My current problem is that I want to move an object over another object with the curser. But these objects overlap each other.
In my example it is a cube (ignores Raycast), which I move with the curser (Worldsace) over the ground (Other cube).

I have already searched for a solution but nothing realy works.
My only solution would be that I just take an empty object and take that as the deepest point of it... but I am sure that it dont work on walls...
I look forward to answers and your solutions.
Thanks in advance.

The 1. script handels my Mouse movement.

The second script moves my Objects (Cube)

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Mouse3D : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static Mouse3D Instance { get; private set; }

    [SerializeField] private LayerMask mouseColliderLayerMask = new LayerMask();
    [SerializeField] private Transform debugVisual; public bool lockMouse;
    public bool showDebugInformations;

    [Header("Debug Only")] public Vector3 mousePosition = Vector3.zero;
    public string objectName;
    public string layerMask;

    public static int x;
    public static int y;
    public static int z;

    private void Awake()
    {
        Instance = this;
    }

    private void Update()
    {
        if (lockMouse)
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
            Cursor.visible = false;
        }
        else
        {
            Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.None;
            Cursor.visible = true;
        }

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, 999f, mouseColliderLayerMask))
        {
            transform.position = raycastHit.point;
        }

        if (showDebugInformations)
        {
            debugVisual.position = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            mousePosition = GetMouseWorldPosition();
            //objectName = raycastHit.transform.parent.name;
            //layerMask = raycastHit.ToString();
        }
    }

    public static Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition() => Instance.GetMouseWorldPosition_Instance();

    private Vector3 GetMouseWorldPosition_Instance()
    {
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out RaycastHit raycastHit, 999f, mouseColliderLayerMask))
        {
            x = (int)raycastHit.point.x; y = (int)raycastHit.point.y; z = (int)raycastHit.point.z;

            return raycastHit.point;
        }
        else
        {
            return Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```

```
using UnityEngine;

public class BuildAssetMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    void Update()
    {
        // moving by 1 unit
        this.transform.SetPositionAndRotation(new Vector3(
            Mathf.RoundToInt(Mouse3D.x),
            Mathf.RoundToInt(Mouse3D.y),
            Mathf.RoundToInt(Mouse3D.z)),
            this.transform.rotation);
    }
}
```

Comment: If this is more about preventing the overlaps you could use [`Physics.ComputePenetartion`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.ComputePenetration.html)  to force your moved object outside of any overlapping object

Comment: Okay I will keep this in mind. I am actualy at work. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Easy solution will be to set world on a grid and each shape knows how much space it occupied.
I would not work if you have free rotation of object allowed.

As I can understand from your code the problem could be that you hitting dragged object. You need to make this object transparent for a `Raycast`.

Comment: I will use different sized objects, so I will not use a grid. 
The objects will only be able to rotate in 90 degrees. Because I am still at the movement, I have not yet impemented the rotation of the objects.
Nevertheless I thank you for your support.

Comment: You can make grid smaller. For example you can have grid to size if 0.1 and object 1 to 10 units in size.

Comment: I dont want to use an Gridsystem. My core tast is to create an buildsystem, where  every object I selected (size differences) sould to move only one by one Unit. The Problem is taht these object are able to overlab to eachother.

Comment: What you say kinda contradicts itself.. moving an object one by one unit to me pretty much sounds like you indeed want a kind of grid system .. maybe just a question of further definition though ;)

Comment: Hahaha xD. No, it acts like an gridsystem, but i dont use an. Only want taht the objects move unit by unit. A grid system is not that what i want. Furthermore my environment base on 3 Dimensions, where a grid have 2 Dimensions. And noo... I dont want to use an 3D Grid xD - **No grids** at all! ^^

Comment: If you make somethink that acts as grid system, looks like a grid system, maybe it will be easier to add grid system?

Comment: Your right in maby in your case, but you cant build an base for example. What I want to say with... you cant really handle different sizes. What is you want to build up to the high... and how to save it in a Json...? So that is not alway a solution. I know that is practicable. And yes my first solution was an grid, but then I´ve got other problems... So I dont want to use grids... maby in an other Project or other cases, but not now.... :)

Answer (score 0):

Hey Guys I found an trick.
In my case, I set the Position hard so i only need the coliders to use the ray,
so I ajust the collder size a bit greather than I wanted it, but if now the values bekommes rounded. they will be always "correctly".
(dont round to the objects position, where you rayed against.)

That was my solution, if you guys have more ideas... let me know them ;)
Thanks four your support.